# Viewstate Not Saved on Force.com Site with URL Rewriter Class

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, urlrewriter

Does anyone have any experience with the viewstate being lost when using a URL Rewrite class on a Force.com site?

A brief overview of my org's use case to explain why this matters.  We have 8-9 Force.com sites active, with the typical business purpose being multi page form data collection.  There are similiar pages across sites, but they're all on the same namespace so they need a prefix to differentiate.  I.e. there could be several ContactInfo pages, several Help pages, but under the default namespace, the page names must be unique.  Since we support a government client, the prefixes can become hideous acronym monstrosities, so we'd like to hide that from the user. Instead of 2015_Q1_SDLC_ABC_Instructions, the URL Rewriter would ideally just show Instructions to the user.

With that out of the way, below is a code example to demonstrate that it's being lost.  Without the rewriter class enabled, you get the expected output.  With it enabled, Page2 shows blank values.

The rewrite class is a bit more complicated than it needs to be for this example, but it's genericized and works as expected.  I can either enter URL_Rewrite_Page1 or Page1, and the commandbutton correctly finds the page.  It just drops the viewstate.  I'm also aware that the redirect default is false, but I explicitly set it to alleviate any confusion.

Anything I'm overlooking here?

**Simple Controller**

```
public class URL_Rewrite_Controller {

public Contact con {get; set;}

public URL_Rewrite_Controller(){
    con = new Contact();
}

public PageReference submit(){
    PageReference ref = new PageReference ('/apex/URL_Rewrite_Page2');
    ref.setRedirect(false);
    return ref;
}
```

**VF Page 1: URL_Rewrite_Page1**

```
    <apex:page controller="URL_Rewrite_Controller" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <body>
        <apex:form>
            <h3>Enter your name:</h3><br/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.FirstName}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.LastName}" />

            <apex:commandButton action="{!submit}" value="Submit"/>
        </apex:form>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

**VF Page 2: URL_Rewrite_Page2**

```
<apex:page controller="URL_Rewrite_Controller" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<body>
    <apex:form>
        <h3>You entered:</h3><br/>
        {!con.FirstName} {!con.LastName}
    </apex:form>
</body>
```

**URL Rewriter**

```
global with sharing class URL_Rewriter implements Site.UrlRewriter {

private Map<String, String> prettyToUglyURLMap {get; set;}
private Map<String, String> uglyToPrettyURLMap {get; set;}

private static final String pagePrefix = 'URL_Rewrite_';

global URL_Rewriter() {
    prettyToUglyURLMap = new Map<String, String>();
    uglyToPrettyURLMap = new Map<String, String>();

    addURLToRewriterMaps('URL_Rewrite_Page1');
    addURLToRewriterMaps('URL_Rewrite_Page2');
}

global void addURLToRewriterMaps(String uglyURL){
    String prettyURL = uglyURL.remove(pagePrefix);

    prettyToUglyURLMap.put(prettyURL, uglyURL);
    uglyToPrettyURLMap.put(uglyURL, prettyURL);
}

global PageReference mapRequestUrl(PageReference myFriendlyUrl){
    String url = myFriendlyUrl.getUrl().remove('/');

    if ( prettyToUglyURLMap.containsKey(url) ){
        return new PageReference( '/' + prettyToUglyURLMap.get(url) );
    }
    return null;
}
global List<PageReference> generateUrlFor(List<PageReference> mySalesforceUrls){

    List<PageReference> myFriendlyUrls = new List<PageReference>();

    for(PageReference mySalesforceUrl : mySalesforceUrls) {

        String url = mySalesforceUrl.getUrl().remove('/');

        if ( uglyToPrettyURLMap.containsKey(url) ){
            myFriendlyUrls.add( new PageReference( '/' + uglyToPrettyURLMap.get(url)));
        }
    }
    return myFriendlyUrls;
}
```

Comment: Forgot to include the output, here's some screenshots:

[Page 1 - With Rewriter](http://imgur.com/YEKfCKM)  
[Page 2 - With Rewriter](http://imgur.com/1l0u8UB)  
[Page 1 - Without Rewriter](http://imgur.com/GQUlGQX)  
[Page 2 - Without Rewriter](http://imgur.com/iTnj15w)